# После обновления pip'а он перестал работать, что делать?

Tags: python, pip

Я ввёл команду: py -m pip install --upgrade pip
Всё вроде обновилось, но если я ввожу какую-то команду с pip'ом, то мне кидает эту ошибку:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python34\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in *run_module_as_main
"**main**", mod_spec)
File "c:\python34\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe_*main**.py", line 5, in 
File "c:\python34\lib\site-packages\pip_*init**.py", line 1, in 
from typing import List, Optional
ImportError: No module named 'typing'

Comment: Переустанови python из установочника

Comment: Я попробовал, но теперь у меня новая ошибка: Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python34\python.exe"  "C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe" list': ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????

Comment: Вторая ошибка уже исправлена, надо было просто обновить pip